# Why doesn't state update in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created a simple component and i have problem with state update. **I know correct solution, but my question is: Why this code doesn't work?**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

type CountdownProps = {
    start: number;
}

export const Countdown: React.FunctionComponent<CountdownProps> = ({start}: CountdownProps) => {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState<number>(start);

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1), 1000);
    }, []);

    return (<>{seconds}</>);
};
```

Comment: Check this one, is this what you are looking for https://codesandbox.io/s/59613617-so-setinterval-for-usestate-1nk2k, and the code is working the only thing is on unmount you need to clear the interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with React hooks when it comes to useInterval that Dan talked about in one of his blog posts in [Overreacted](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

> The problem is that `useEffect` captures the the initial value passed to CountDown `initValue` from the first render. We never re-apply the effect so the closure in setInterval always references the `initValue` from the first render, and `initValue - 1` is always `initValue`.

Fun fact

> You can actually check that the interval is actually updating every second by adding a `console.log` to the statement but it's always getting `initValue`. 
>    Try it out here https://repl.it/repls/MedicalMealyPentagon

For a solution, please read the article above.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i'm looking for <3 Now, i can sleep peacefully

Comment: You should mention `useInterval`, otherwise, your answer is incomplete and depends on an off-site article.

Answer (score 2):

Into the setTimeout or setInterval, you have not accessed to the global context and you have to call the seconds callback function which will give you the latest value and you need to return new seconds value as below:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

type CountdownProps = {
    start: number;
}

export const Countdown: React.FunctionComponent<CountdownProps> = ({start}) => {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState<number>(start);

    useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => setSeconds(preSeconds => preSeconds - 1), 1000);
    }, []);

    return (<>{seconds}</>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value of `seconds` is never updated in the fonction you provide to setInterval. Your function is run every 1000ms but the value does not change because `seconds` in the provided function is never updated.

Instead of setInterval you could use setTimeout and have useEffect depend on `seconds` like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(100);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setSeconds(seconds - 1), 1000);
  }, [seconds]);

  return <>{seconds}</>;
}
```

Comment: Why state seconds is not updated? I call setSeconds(seconds - 1), that function updates seconds

Comment: Yes you call it but the value of seconds is still the initial one, because useEffect captures only the initial value as Mounir Dhahri explains it well in his answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add constructor value to usestate(I Added 0)
Also the second argument of **useEffect** should be **seconds**

Also i change **React.FunctionComponent** to **React.FC**

The more information about second argument:

> The second argument to React's useEffect hook is an array of
>   dependencies for your useEffect callback. When any value in that array
>   changes, the effect callback is re-run.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

type CountdownProps = {
    start: number;
}

const Countdown: React.FC<CountdownProps> = ({start}: CountdownProps) => {

    start = 0;
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState<number>(start);

    useEffect(() => { const id = setInterval(() => { setSeconds(seconds - 1) }, 1000); return () => clearInterval(id); }, [seconds])

    return (<>{seconds}</>);
};

export default Countdown;
```

Comment: Cause this is bad answer, initialParam in stateHook is ok and in this solution what u posted setInterval function is forked for every second

Comment: this is correct use useEffect hook:
`
    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setInterval(() => {
            setSeconds(seconds - 1)
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(id);
    }, [seconds]);
`

Comment: yea with depependies on seconds, but i need to know why my code doesn't work :( Imho its correct

Comment: Maybe constructor need value - add start=0 ?

Comment: if you copy this code to you, it will work. Countdown from x to infinity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205453/discussion-between-piotr-zak-and-ashwel).